# Set a trading date based on time 6am to 6am

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What would be the optimal way to set a trading date based on time. I want to set the invoice date as the current trading date based on 6am to 6am on the following day. I want to use the current time to return the correct trading date for night club billing. To be clear, if the time is 1am then the trading date is the previous date. The next day's trading will begin at 6am.

Platform is ruby 2, rails 4, postgresql.

Comment: This isn't clear.  What do you mean by "set a trading date"?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth in other words you can think of it as a **cut-off** time. As you do in human resources/payroll there will be a "cut-off" date where all submitted hours of work will be submitted for that date. Anything after this date will be included in the next month pay. I believe mango is referring to the same similar idea but with time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

substract 6 hous from now before converting it to a date:

```
trading_day = 6.hours.ago.to_date
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly the concise answer I was looking for!